# calling a static parameter from one public class to another

Tags: c#, static

I'm trying to write a multi-threaded app , and I need to use `Monitoer.Enter/Exit/Wait/Pulse`
I've created a Lock object and used it in its own class like that

```
public partial class domain 
    /*I dont sure this is the good practice way to mange DDD Layers (if anybody have a comment about it)*/
{

   Public class Peer2PeerCom
   {
    public static readonly object locker = new object();
    //other stuff here
    //...
    //somwhere here
    Monitor.Pulse(locker);
   }   
}
```

in the other class I want/need to use the locker like that

```
public class Control
{
public domain.Peer2PeerCom Dom_P2PCom = new domain.Peer2PeerCom();
internal void connection ( int port , string IpAdress)
 {
  Monitor.Enter(Dom_P2PCom.locker);
  //do stuff here
  Monitor.wait(Dom_P2PCom.locker);
  //..
  Monitor.Exit(Dom_P2PCom.locker);
 }
}
```

But when I try I cannot recognize the `locker` , I think it is because it is `static` but I dont understand how to correct it without making the entire class static

Comment: Don't you mean `Peer2PeerCom.locker` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access a *static* member via a reference. That doesn't work in C#, fortunately - it can lead to very misleading code where it's allowed, e.g. in Java.

Instead, you should use the name of the class to access a static member:

```
lock (domain.Peer2PeerCom.locker)
{
    ...
    // This should probably be in a while loop...
    Monitor.Wait(domain.Peer2PeerCom.locker);
}
```

(I've used `lock` rather than explicitly calling `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` - it's more idiomatic, and easier to get right - in the code you've given, any exception in the code after entering the monitor would have cause the monitor to be "leaked" - you wouldn't have exited it.)

In general, I'd strongly recommend *against* using a public static field for a shared lock like this. It makes it *much* harder to reason about what's using the lock than if it's private within a class. (I'd recommend against public fields in general, along with underscores in class names, classes which are nested for no particular reason, and a class name of `domain`, too...)

Comment: thank you for the complete answer and good suggestions , but I've few questions
1)why should I put the Monitor.wait in a while loop ? 
2)what do you mean by monitor "leaking"
3)I agree about the public static but How can I do it otherwise?

Comment: @LordTitiKaka: 1) Usually you only want to wait if a particular condition isn't satisfied; you usually want to loop until it *is* satisfied; 2) it means the thread would still "own" the monitor even though you don't want it to, probably leading to deadlock or at least unwanted behaviour; 3) we don't have enough information about what you're trying to achieve to give an alternative. You might want to ask a new question with more information.

Comment: 1) correct me if I'm wrong but Monitor.Wait will stuck the thread until Monitor.Pulse will fire somewhere , isn't it ? I mean if I'm right the While will stuck
2) you are right , I didnt think about it , I'll correct my ways :)

Comment: @LordTitiKaka: Yes, unless there are *spurious wakeups*, where `Monitor.Wait` returns without a pulse. It's not clear to me whether or not that's still a problem, but *usually* if you think more about your design you'll find there's a condition which is sensible to check for anyway.